# Replace callback works in VS2013 but not in ideone

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, callback

Playing around with regex in VB.NET today and testing a simple replace callback lambda.

The code compiles perfectly in VS2013, but ideone screams about it. Wondering if a VB.NET pro would have some insight about this. :)

The regex is unimportant, it's a random example to test the feature. What I care about is the replace callback. I'm quite keen on keeping the MatchEvaluator inline inside the Replace, as shown below, as opposed to declaring the function separately.

In VS2013, the following code correctly outputs AAA111000 (no warnings, no errors). But [ideone doesn't like it](https://ideone.com/CbhVBE): `prog.vb (8,1) : Error VBNC90019: Expected ')'`.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
Sub Main()
Dim SomeRegex As New Regex("\d{3}")
Dim Subject As String = "AAA123456"
Dim NewString As String = SomeRegex.Replace(Subject,
                    Function(m As Match)
                        If (m.Groups(0).Value = "123") Then
                            Return "111"
                        Else 
                            Return "000"
                        End If
                     End Function                        
                    )
Console.WriteLine(NewString)
Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "Press Key")
 Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Ideone and VB.NET don't fit together, it's unusable.

Comment: According to their FAQ they're using mono 2.4.2.3 for VB.Net. My guess would be that lambdas weren't fully supported then. https://ideone.com/faq

Comment: @ChrisHaas Good find! Do you think there is an alternate, more explicit lambda syntax that ideone might swallow? Wondering if it would be happier if the lambda call somehow mentioned MatchEvaluator, but unsure of correct syntax if any.

Comment: I'd dig into mono a little deeper if I were you and see what they support at that version. Failing that I'd just not bother too much and write a normal callback method instead of an anonymous function.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `Ideone and VB.NET don't fit together` This begs the question: do you happen to know an online tester that plays well with VB.NET? I know, asking for a tool recommendation is off-topic. :)

Comment: @zx81: no, otherwise i would have mentioned it.

Comment: My first guess would be the lambda.  If it is still broke and your sure they use Mono, try compiling it in mono.

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET doesn't seem to work well with Ideone.  I think perhaps in this case, the lack of line continuation characters is throwing you off, but even if you fix that, you will likely have other issues.